# JavaScript: Get clickevent coordinates of a programatically simulated click on HTML element

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, click, mousewheel

I need to get clickevent's screenX/screenY and clientX/clientY (Coordinates) of an HTML DOM element by programatically simulating click event on it, simplified code shown below.

Problem: When the element is manually clicked - the Coordinates are fine and present (as can be inspected in the console), HOWEVER when programatically clicked, the Coordinates are all 0.

Q1: Why the coordinates are 0 (we have a well positioned element) ?
Q2: What can be adjusted, so as to get the coordinates ?

Note: The ultimate goal is to devise a C# Selenium IJavaScriptExecutor compatible JavaScript code, so as to capture (any-set-of) current Coordinates of an HTML element with known id attribute (the captured Coordinates to be further used as input coordinates for creation and simulation of a mousewheel event, needed for zooming).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h1> Hello </h1>
    <h1 id="num1">TEST</h1>

  <script>
    var myVar = document.getElementById("num1");
    myVar.onclick = function(event){ myFunc(event); };   // manually working fine 
   
    myVar.click();    // not yielding Coordinates 
   
    function myFunc(e){
      console.log(e);  
    }
  </script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you try using https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent instead to trigger the click?

Comment: Tested with the patterns in MDN (named there as 'old' and 'new' stile). Both behave as .click() on the element, i.e. no Coordinates added to the captured event object

Answer (score 0):

Q1: If your mouse was outside browser\page window,when you simulate click, it probably will be 0\0.
Q2: Something like [this](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/8535/selenium-how-to-click-at-x-y-coordinates) should solve your problem

Comment: AQ1C: Tested with mouse over the page window, no Coordinates added
AQ2C: Tese were the initial tests that yielded no suitable result, which necessitated further investigations in IJavaScriptExecutor of Selenium...however some suitable lib found, will post results if successful... Thanks for the notes